# How to prevent anchor href action from child element click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to prevent the page from reloading when the user clicks on the close button. The anchor should only work when the user clicks anywhere expect close button. I have used stopPropagation but it seems not working in this case. here is my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9h1bw037/5/)

```
<a href="https://jsfiddle.net/9h1bw037/">
  <div>go to google</div>
  <button class="close">
    close
  </button>
</a>


$('.close').click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation()
  console.log('clicked')
})
```

Comment: I think it is wrong to wrap a button in an anchor tag. Any reason you are doing that?

Comment: yes, the button will open a popup where a user can perform other actions. But if he clicks anywhere else it should redirect. We can replace button with any other element

Comment: post your react code. you may have an issue in your code

Comment: you can take the button outside of the anchor tag, set an absolute positioning on the button and place it above the anchor tag with a z index and give you anchor tag some width and height

Answer (score 2):

You can try with `return false`
Updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9h1bw037/6/)

```
$('.close').click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation()
  console.log('clicked')
  return false;
})
```

For react you can try this example [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pintus/wa30wz0z/1/)

```
class Hello extends React.Component {
    handleClose = (e) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    }

  handleAnchor = () => {
    window.location="https://jsfiddle.net"
  }

  render() {
    return <div>
    <a onClick={this.handleAnchor}>
      <div>Go to google</div>
      <button onClick={this.handleClose}>
        close
      </button>
    </a>
    </div>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello name="World" />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Comment: actually I was facing this issue with react. There I have also used return false but it does not seems to work there. anyways thanks for answer. I though it would be common issue but now it seems to be only with reactjs

Comment: Maybe you might like to mention that you are using `react` in your question - returning false is the obvious way to go, *given the question as-is*.

Comment: Using React, I had to use both `e.stopPropagation()` and `return false`